# XNA multiples cubes

Tags: c#, xna, voxel

firstly, forgive my English, I'm French...
I wrote a code that does not work.
I want to draw a mutliples blocks, like Minecraft, but in Voxel.
on one side of my map, the result is good:

[This render is opaque, good !](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/967x615q90/820/roas.png)

but on the other side, I get this:

[But in this side of my map, it's no good :(](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1320x839q90/820/nvif.png)

Some faces appear through some other faces...
Who has an idea ? My Normals ?

My function Remake() is not used, it's for remove faces...

```
    namespace LandOfCube.Models
{
    class Block
    {
        VertexBuffer instanceBuffer;
       public enum Form
        {
            all,
            noUp,
            noDown,
            noRight,
            noLeft,
            noFront,
            noBack
        }
       public Form cubeForm = Form.all;

        GraphicsDevice Graphics;
        Effect shader;
        private VertexBuffer vb;
        Color CubeColor;
        public Vector3 pos;

        VertexPositionColorNormal[] vertices;
        VertexPositionColorNormal[] verticesNoUp;
        VertexPositionColorNormal[] verticesNoDown;
        VertexPositionColorNormal[] verticesNoFront;
        VertexPositionColorNormal[] verticesNoBack;
        VertexPositionColorNormal[] verticesNoRight;
        VertexPositionColorNormal[] verticesNoLeft;


        private VertexPositionColorNormal[] Front = new VertexPositionColorNormal[5];
        private VertexPositionColorNormal[] Back = new VertexPositionColorNormal[5];
        private VertexPositionColorNormal[] Right = new VertexPositionColorNormal[5];
        private VertexPositionColorNormal[] Up = new VertexPositionColorNormal[5];
        private VertexPositionColorNormal[] Left = new VertexPositionColorNormal[5];
        private VertexPositionColorNormal[] Down = new VertexPositionColorNormal[5];

        public Vector3 normalFront = Vector3.Forward;
        public Vector3 normalBack = Vector3.Backward;
        public Vector3 normalTop = Vector3.Up;
        public Vector3 normalBottom = Vector3.Down;
        public Vector3 normalLeft = Vector3.Left;
        public Vector3 normalRight = Vector3.Right;

        public Block(GraphicsDevice graph, Color color, Vector3 position, ContentManager content)
        {


            Graphics = graph;

            shader = content.Load<Effect>("effects");
            CubeColor = color;
            pos = position;

            Init();
            SetVertices();

        }





        bool test = false;
        public void Draw(Camera camera)
        {



            Graphics.SetVertexBuffer(vb);

            shader.CurrentTechnique = shader.Techniques["Colored"];


            shader.Parameters["xView"].SetValue(camera.View);
            shader.Parameters["xProjection"].SetValue(camera.Projection);
            shader.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(Matrix.Identity);
            Vector3 lightDirection = new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            lightDirection.Normalize();
            shader.Parameters["xLightDirection"].SetValue(lightDirection);
            shader.Parameters["xAmbient"].SetValue(0.1f);
            shader.Parameters["xEnableLighting"].SetValue(true);


            foreach (EffectPass pass in shader.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {

                pass.Apply();
                this.Graphics.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, vertices.Length / 3);
            }




        }








        #region Methode abstraites

        private void Init()
        {

            InitFront();
            InitBack();
            InitDown();
            InitUp();
            InitLeft();
            InitRight();
        }



        public void Remake()
        {
            switch (cubeForm)
            {
                case Form.noBack:
                    vertices = verticesNoBack;
                    break;
                case Form.noFront:
                    vertices = verticesNoFront;
                    break;
                case Form.noUp:
                    vertices = verticesNoUp;
                    break;
                case Form.noDown:
                    vertices = verticesNoDown;
                    break;
                case Form.noRight:
                    vertices = verticesNoRight;
                    break;
                case Form.noLeft:
                    vertices = verticesNoLeft;
                    break;
            }
            vb = new VertexBuffer(Graphics, typeof(VertexPositionColorNormal), vertices.Length, BufferUsage.None);
            vb.SetData(vertices);

            verticesNoBack = null;
            verticesNoDown = null;
            verticesNoFront = null;
            verticesNoLeft = null;
            verticesNoRight = null;
            verticesNoUp = null;

            test = true;
        }




        public void SetVertices()
        {
            this.vertices = new VertexPositionColorNormal[36];
            int y = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Up[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Down[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Front[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Back[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Right[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Left[x]; y++;
            }

            setNoBack();
            setNoFront();
            setNoUp();
            setNoDown();
            setNoRight();
            setNoLeft();

            vb = new VertexBuffer(Graphics, typeof(VertexPositionColorNormal), vertices.Length, BufferUsage.None);
            vb.SetData(vertices);
            Clean();
        }

        #region InitFaces

        public void setNoBack()
        {
            this.verticesNoBack = new VertexPositionColorNormal[30];
            int y = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Up[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Down[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Front[x]; y++;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Right[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Left[x]; y++;
            }
        }
        public void setNoFront()
        {
            this.verticesNoFront = new VertexPositionColorNormal[30];
            int y = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Up[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Down[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Back[x]; y++;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Right[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Left[x]; y++;
            }
        }
        public void setNoUp()
        {
            this.verticesNoUp = new VertexPositionColorNormal[30];
            int y = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Front[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Down[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Back[x]; y++;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Right[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Left[x]; y++;
            }
        }
        public void setNoDown()
        {
            this.verticesNoFront = new VertexPositionColorNormal[30];
            int y = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Up[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Front[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Back[x]; y++;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Right[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Left[x]; y++;
            }
        }
        public void setNoLeft()
        {
            this.verticesNoLeft = new VertexPositionColorNormal[30];
            int y = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Up[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Down[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Back[x]; y++;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Right[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Front[x]; y++;
            }
        }
        public void setNoRight()
        {
            this.verticesNoRight = new VertexPositionColorNormal[30];
            int y = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Up[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Down[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Back[x]; y++;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Front[x]; y++;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                this.vertices[y] = Left[x]; y++;
            }
        }


        public void InitFront()
        {
            this.Front = new VertexPositionColorNormal[6];

            Front[0].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Front[0].Color = Color.Blue;
            Front[0].Normal = normalFront;
            Front[1].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Front[1].Color = Color.Blue;
            Front[1].Normal = normalFront;
            Front[2].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Front[2].Color = Color.Blue;
            Front[2].Normal = normalFront;


            Front[3].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Front[3].Color = Color.Blue;
            Front[3].Normal = normalFront;
            Front[4].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Front[4].Color = Color.Blue;
            Front[4].Normal = normalFront;
            Front[5].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Front[5].Color = Color.Blue;
            Front[5].Normal = normalFront;
        }
        public void InitBack()
        {
            this.Back = new VertexPositionColorNormal[6];

            Back[0].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Back[0].Color = Color.Red;
            Back[0].Normal = normalBack;
            Back[1].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Back[1].Color = Color.Red;
            Back[1].Normal = normalBack;
            Back[2].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Back[2].Color = Color.Red;
            Back[2].Normal = normalBack;


            Back[3].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Back[3].Color = Color.Red;
            Back[3].Normal = normalBack;
            Back[4].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Back[4].Color = Color.Red;
            Back[4].Normal = normalBack;
            Back[5].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Back[5].Color = Color.Red;
            Back[5].Normal = normalBack;
        }
        public void InitUp()
        {
            this.Up = new VertexPositionColorNormal[6];

            Up[0].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Up[0].Color = Color.Black;
            Up[0].Normal = normalTop;
            Up[1].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Up[1].Color = Color.Black;
            Up[1].Normal = normalTop;
            Up[2].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Up[2].Color = Color.Black;
            Up[2].Normal = normalTop;


            Up[3].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Up[3].Color = Color.Black;
            Up[3].Normal = normalTop;
            Up[4].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Up[4].Color = Color.Black;
            Up[4].Normal = normalTop;
            Up[5].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Up[5].Color = Color.Black;
            Up[5].Normal = normalTop;
        }
        public void InitDown()
        {
            this.Down = new VertexPositionColorNormal[6];

            Down[0].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Down[0].Color = Color.Orange;
            Down[0].Normal = normalBottom;
            Down[1].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Down[1].Color = Color.Orange;
            Down[1].Normal = normalBottom;
            Down[2].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Down[2].Color = Color.Orange;
            Down[2].Normal = normalBottom;


            Down[3].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Down[3].Color = Color.Orange;
            Down[3].Normal = normalBottom;
            Down[4].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Down[4].Color = Color.Orange;
            Down[4].Normal = normalBottom;
            Down[5].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Down[5].Color = Color.Orange;
            Down[5].Normal = normalBottom;
        }
        public void InitRight()
        {
            this.Right = new VertexPositionColorNormal[6];

            Right[0].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Right[0].Color = Color.Green;
            Right[0].Normal = normalRight;
            Right[1].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Right[1].Color = Color.Green;
            Right[1].Normal = normalRight;
            Right[2].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Right[2].Color = Color.Green;
            Right[3].Normal = normalRight;


            Right[3].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z + 1);
            Right[3].Color = Color.Green;
            Right[3].Normal = normalRight;
            Right[4].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Right[4].Color = Color.Green;
            Right[4].Normal = normalRight;
            Right[5].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z + 1);
            Right[5].Color = Color.Green;
            Right[5].Normal = normalRight;
        }
        public void InitLeft()
        {
            this.Left = new VertexPositionColorNormal[6];

            Left[0].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Left[0].Color = Color.Aqua;
            Left[0].Normal = normalLeft;
            Left[1].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Left[1].Color = Color.Aqua;
            Left[1].Normal = normalLeft;
            Left[2].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Left[2].Color = Color.Aqua;
            Left[2].Normal = normalLeft;


            Left[3].Position = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Left[3].Color = Color.Aqua;
            Left[3].Normal = normalLeft;
            Left[4].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y, pos.Z);
            Left[4].Color = Color.Aqua;
            Left[4].Normal = normalLeft;
            Left[5].Position = new Vector3(pos.X + 1, pos.Y + 1, pos.Z);
            Left[5].Color = Color.Aqua;
            Left[5].Normal = normalLeft;
        }

        #endregion
        private void setTriangleNormal(VertexPositionColorNormal v1, VertexPositionColorNormal v2, VertexPositionColorNormal v3)
        {

            Vector3 side1 = v1.Position - v3.Position;
            Vector3 side2 = v1.Position - v2.Position;
            Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(side1, side2);

            v1.Normal += normal;
            v2.Normal += normal;
            v3.Normal += normal;

            v1.Position.Normalize();
            v1.Position.Normalize();
            v1.Position.Normalize();
        }



        public void Clean()
        {
            Front = null;
            Back = null;
            Right = null;
            Left = null;
            Up = null;
            Down = null;

        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course we need the code.

Comment: I suspect an invalid depth buffer or state. Have you tampered with these settings?

Comment: No, I don't have touched this settings :/

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are winding the vertices on the back sides of the cubes in the wrong direction, making their normal point to the inside of the cube instead of the outside.  One very common optimization in 3d code is to only draw triangles that have a normal facing the camera.

Comment: That's not a common optimization. In fact, I don't know of any engine that does that. You probably mean backface culling. However, the normal has nothing to do with backface culling. It's all the vertices' winding order that determine if a face is culled or not. Anyway, that's not the case as you can see in the code.

Comment: Backface culling is exactly what I'm referring to.  It is directly related to the surface normal.  Any surface that has a normal pointing away from the camera is discarded.  Getting the winding order wrong will flip the normal and cause the surface to get culled.

Comment: Please be careful with your wording. A normal is an attribute of a vertex. Usually, those attributes are interpolated accross faces. This attribute is not involved in backface culling. We could introduce another normal for faces, which depends only on the vertices' positions. We could define culling upon this value. However, this is abiguous and therefore not commonly used. Therefore, we only speak of winding order. Not of another face normal.

Comment: I think you might want to double check yourself here.  The normal is a property of a plane, not a vertex.  The vertex is a simple position in 3D space, nothing more.  The plane defined by 3 vertices is what has the `normal`; the direction of which is defined by the winding order.  The normal at each vertex is actually calulated by interpolating from the center of it's neighbor planes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_normal   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling

Comment: That's not what I meant. When you specify geometry, you assign multiple attributes to vertices - position, color, texture coordinates, normal (the vertex is not only a position, but a node in a graph). This normal is interpolated across faces in the rasterizer stage to be used for lighting. Culling takes place before rasterizing. Yes, culling can be said to use the surface normal (which is different from the interpolated vertex normal). But as I said, this can quickly lead to confusion, so I don't recommend using this definition.